# ATM pcap file to Ethernet Pcap file

Tags: network-programming, pcap, winpcap

I am looking for .pcap file format of ATM.Its needed in my project.I am looking for mechanism so that ATM pcap file can be converted to Ethernet pcap file

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one link-layer header type for ATM.  [The list of link-layer header type values](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) has both `LINKTYPE_ATM_RFC1483`/`DLT_ATM_RFC1483`, where the packets begin with an IEEE 802.2 header, and `LINKTYPE_SUNATM`/`DLT_SUNATM`, where the packets being with [a SunATM header](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_SUNATM.html).  There may be some other link-layer header types being used as well; you'll have to determine which of them the ATM pcap files you're looking at use.

Comment: First of all my concern is to capture pcap which contains ATM.How can i do that using wire-shark??Then I will be needing to convert that into Ethernet format.

Comment: What operating system is the machine on which you want to capture traffic running?

Comment: preferably on Windows7 or Ubuntu.

Comment: On Windows, WinPcap doesn't support ATM devices, so you won't be able to capture on Windows 7.  On Ubuntu, it'll probably be `DLT_ATM_RFC1483`; to convert that to Ethernet, you'll have to write your own code that looks at the 802.2 LLC header and, if it's 802.2 + SNAP with an OUI of 0, creates a fake Ethernet header with the SNAP PID as the Ethertype and strips off the 802.2+SNAP header, and otherwise creates a fake Ethernet header with the appropriate length and puts the 802.2 LLC header and the rest of the packet after it.